# Emacs/shell symbolic links behavior

Tags: emacs, hyperlink

I have a symbolic link ~/c from my home directory to ~/a/b/c/. After

cd ~/c

I land in ~/a/b/c and then fire up emacs. In emacs I open a file using Ctrl-x Ctrl-f. The minibuffer shows ~/c/, not ~/a/b/c, and when I enter ../ I get a listing of my home directory, rather than a listing of ~/a/b.

I find that weird. Is there a way to prevent emacs from following symbolic links backwards? I have tried

(defun file-symlink-p (FILENAME) nil)

with no success. Interestingly, different shells handle symbolic links differently:

cat ~/c/../

expands to directory b for csh, but to ~/ in bash. So emacs seems to be closer to the bash behavior. I favor the csh approach really.

Any hints highly appreciated.

Comment: Internally, Emacs needs to keep track of the "truename" of each file, in order to properly handle concurrency. Maybe there could still be a way to present the file name to the user in a non-canonical form.